# fetch: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (but for most users it works)

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am doing a request with fetch in a React component. For the vast majority of users it works fine, but one user reported these errors:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE 
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

It looks like similar requests are working for them, though. This came from Edge but they said they had the same problem in Chrome.

This is a same-origin request so I'm sure it can't be a CORS issue. Could something like this be caused by an ad blocker or firewall settings?

Code that generates the fetch request (likely not relevant):

```
function fetchWrapper(url, data, options, noModals) {
    var body;
    if (data instanceof FormData) {
        body = data;
    } elseif (data !== null) {
        body = JSON.stringify(data);
    }
    options.body = body;
    if (!options.method) {
        options.method = "POST";
    }

    return fetch(url, options).then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            return response.json().then(json => {
                var error = (json && json.error) || response.statusText;
                var message = "";
                if (json.error && errors[json.error]) {
                    error = errors[json.error];
                }
                if (json.error && messages[json.error]) {
                    message = messages[json.error];
                }
                // Bad request - show the error message to the user
                if (response.status >= 400 && response.status < 500) {
                    return handleError(noModals, error, message);
                } else { // server error
                    error = errors.wrong;
                    message = messages.wrong;

                    return handleError(noModals, error, message, json ? json.error : "Unknown error");
                }
            })
        }
        return response.json().then(json => {
            // the response returned a success code but there is an error message
            if (json.error) {
                return handleError(noModals, json.error);
            }
            return json;
        });
    }).catch(reason => { // JavaScript or network error
        console.log(reason); // this is where the TypeError is printed
        // not showing an error to the user
    });
}
```

As for the server code, it's a PHP backend but I can't see any reason why it would return an empty response. I couldn't reproduce the issue even after logging in as that user and repeating their action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use a npm package called `axios`. With the package you can easily create a request.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const response = axios.get('[url]');
```

Just replace [ulr] with the url you want to request and the data will be stored in the response variable.

If that doesn't work you could try to make the request async with `await axios`.

Comment: Thanks. It seems a bit odd to accept this as the answer as it sidesteps whatever causes this with the fetch API. But switching to axios did solve the issue and it was easy to switch over